# Can't toggle drawer in stack navigator from custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have [`StackNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) component with a custom header for [`DrawerNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html).
The custom header has a button that should toggle Drawer on press. I have added the action as provided in React Navigation docs but doesn't work.

A snack with issue can be found [here](https://snack.expo.io/@hotes/drawer-issue)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import: `import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';`

And then just use it inside **Header**:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
 return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 25}}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
        title="Toggle"
        color="#841584" />
    </View>)
}
```

Comment: I want to toggle drawer on press of a view or a icon instead of a button. can you advise?

Comment: Just use TouchableOpacity (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) with the same onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}